# Focus() is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working in some bootstrap templates and I need that when I click some element I can edit it, for example if there is a `<span>some text</span>`
and I click it can edit the text.

So, I tried it with the function `focus()`, but is not working, I don't know if there is a conflict with bootstrap or what because I was doing some testing and every element outside my container class work the `focus()`, but if is inside it doesn't work.

The idea is make all elements focusable, even if I assign an Id to an element, doesn't work.
I hope you can help me with this.

Thank you.

I have a example here http://jsfiddle.net/d4fyoy41/

Answer (score 5):

What you want is the [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.contentEditable) attribute. `focus` is primarily for focusing into an `input` or `textarea`; any other element cannot be typed in unless explicitly editable. Once an element is editable, then `focus()` will work. Beware that not all browsers support this well (like iPad's Safari).

Comment: you can also look at the `designMode` attribute. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.designMode